# Receiving http status code with grails

Tags: http, grails, get, http-status-codes

I'm trying to receive status code with url calls.(Using grails)

```
def http = new HttpResponseDecorator(url)
    // Authentication header
    http.auth.basic(username, password)
    // Http request method. Pulls out json file
    http.request(Method.GET) {
        response.success = {
            render "Success!"
        }
        response.failure = { resp ->;
            render resp
        }
    }
```

Trying this code snippet to receive make url calls, but I can't figure out how to pull out status code from this.

What I want to do is sending error messages depending on what status code I'm getting.(for example, 400 prints forbidden message of my choice)

Any suggestions for a class to receive status code of the GET calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `resp` argument to your `response.failure` closure has a `status` you can check.

```
response.failiure = { resp ->
    if (resp.status == 400) {
        // render forbidden message
    }
}
```

See the [Response Handlers](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki/Response-Handlers) section of the httpbuilder docs for more information and examples.